# Using Qt Creator with Git version control

Tags: git, qt-creator

I’ve recently installed git and initialized a git repo in my project folder. I can commit and checkout without any issues through the command line, but for some reason the gui in qt creator claims my connection has timed out. Im running windows…. Any ideas?

Error message(s):

21:15 Executing: git status –u
Unable to obtain the status: Error: Git timed out

Please let me know if any further clarification is needed!

I've posted this on both qt forums, but no one seems to know how to solve the issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Comment: Is version an issue? I can't find much documentation regarding the issue online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughs:

- Are you using Cygwin for the command line? If so, Qt Creator might fail because either `git` or the required `ssh` executables can not be found. How do you connect to the remote repository?
- I'm quite sure this is because Qt Creator can not find the `git` executable. Try setting the exact path of the `git` executable in Qt Creator's settings.